# HIbernate @manytomany criteria on the connection table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following @manytomany:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_relation", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "child_id") })
    private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<Category>();
```

I would like to create a Criteria that would bring all the Cateogry that their parent market_id is x.

```
Category looks like this:
     -id
     -name
     -market_id
Cateogry_relation
     -id
     -category_id
     -child_id
```

It should be something similar to

```
select category_relation.child_id from category,category_relation where category.market_category_id = 2984 and category_relation.category_id = category.id
```

but instead of returning only the child_id it would return the full category objects
I wrote the following:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Category.class);
criteria.createCriteria("children").add(Restrictions.eq("parent_id", parentId));
```

But it doesn't work - I get an exception that Category doesn't have parent_id field

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you really need Criteria query or can you use JPQL query ?

Comment: I don't mind using HQL. what is JPQL - never used it. I prefer to use either Criteria or HQL

Comment: JPQL is Java Persistence Query Language. According to the docs: `A JPQL query is always a valid HQL query, the reverse is not true however.` I can help you with thejpql/hql query, but whats the other entity - thats the owner of `Set<Category> children`?

Comment: Category owns children of Category. It's like a tree

Comment: PS: And may you give more detail what you are trying to do, because it's not clear from the question. I cannot understand the sample "query" you've given

Comment: I am trying to get all the categories that their parent_id is for instance 18165

Comment: Thanks I managed via SQL . I wanted to do it via Criteria but probaly it's not gonna owrk. I will delete the question

Comment: don't delete it, it;s very interesting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you can do:

```
Category parent = entityManager.find(Category.class, parentId);
Set<Category> children = parent.getChildren();
```

Or if insist on using a query

```
select child from Category parent join parent.children child where parent.id = :parentId
```

### Update:

I've tested it and it works on my side. Here is my Category impl:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cat_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inverse_cat_id"))
    private Set<Category> children = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

And when I run the query I get the parent's children

**PS** (on your exception): **you cannot specify columns in your queries. You can only specify entity (class) `fields`**

**PS2**: I've seen that you only need the children ids and updated the query

**QUOTE:**

> What if I need to get based on market_category_id field?

With this query you'll get the children based on parent's market_id

```
select child from Category parent join parent.children child where parent.market_id = :parentId
```

Comment: Hmm, I havent tested it, but I'll do in a minute

Comment: What if I need to get based on market_category_id field?

Comment: See the last query, which will return the children's ids based on their parent market_id

Comment: Correct -but I need the full object, otherwise I will need to do find by id for each :( is ther ea way?

Comment: :D of course just remove the `.id` part - i'll update the query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49084/discussion-between-dejel-and-svetlin-zarev)